# slope equation calculation for a line

Tags: slope

when slope m=0 it is a straight horizontal line and when slope is vertical line..I mean what is the value for slope m to get vertical line?I think that for vertical line, slope is m=0 also.

Comment: no, slope of vertical line is undefined (due to division by $0$); slope $m=0$ is horizontal line

Comment: A vertical line is not a function by the [vertical line test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_line_test), but you can think of the slope $m$ as $\pm \infty$.

Comment: The slope is defined as $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ in the case of a line for arbitary two points. For a vertical line, we can therefore not have slope $0$. But with $x=a$ , a vertical line can nevertheless be described.

Comment: why it is undefined it is very normal concept....A horizontal plane can have zero slope and zero is a number but infinity is not a number...